# Disable orange higlight on a Menu using Android

Tags: css

A link(Menu) is highlighted by orange color after the user tap on it on android browser. I would like to remove this highlight.
I tried to search but and found some answers but when i tried it didn't work in my case. Is there anyone who can guide me?

```css
ul {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  float: right;
  li {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 40px;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: 900;
    letter-spacing: 0.04rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the tap-highlight being applied to the `a` tag within the list item?

Comment: Yes it is, but it doesnt work also

Comment: Share your HTML also, please.

Comment: Were using sitecore and edit the file through visual studio, I only have access on css file at the moment as soon as my colleague help me to find it I will post it here immediately.

Comment: Just get the HTML from the code inspector in the browser, that will be enough. Have you tried modifying :active, :focus? If there's an <a> within the <li>, it might fix this.

Comment: @Victoria heres the html code

Comment: I will try to post it again I didn't format the code  :(

Comment: **I solve the problem by this code**  ' #service-navigation ul li a:focus, select:focus, service-texts:focus, li:focus {
        outline: none;
       }'

Comment: @pham, you can answer your own question. Make sue you add the HTML to the code so that it helps others.